# NVIDIA driver couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so and can't install cuda successfully

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I have following nvidia graphics card in my pc (ubuntu18.04LTS)
Intel i5 9600K
NVIDIA GeForce RTX2070

I have install cuda and nvidia drivers with following way

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda cuda-drivers
sudo reboot
```

then

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.
```

And I search libnvidia-ml.so

```
ls /usr/lib/nvidia
pre-install
```

Any suggestion to get this working? Where does nvidia-smi try to find the libnvidia-ml.so?

Comment: Does anything in this link help? https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=boot_issue_with_nvidia_manjaro_linux_install_vs_codes_open_source_version_and_more&utm_term=2019-04-14

Comment: Check if the NVIDIA GPU / driver is installed.
I found on webpage of NVIDIA a new release of driver, https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145182/en-us

Comment: I think my way of installing cuda can install drivers too. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html

Comment: Check if nvidia-smi is in /usr/bin (without /nvidia), that's where the cuda-executables typically are installed.

Answer (score 1):

I soloved this problem.
remove all cuda and nvidia-drivers

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*
sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda-*
```

and then
auto install drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

to check drivers are successfully installed

```
nvidia-smi
```

then, install cuda-10.0(i'll use tensorflow=1.13.1)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
sudo apt-get install cuda-10.0
```

install cudnn

```
echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcudnn7-dev=7.5.0.56-1+cuda10.0
```

setting path

```
sudo cp -a cuda/lib64/* /usr/lib/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp -a cuda/include/* /usr/lib/cuda/include/
```